# Error al compilar o hacer rebuild a mi proyecto

Tags: android, app

una consulta, lo que pasa es que al querer compilar mi proyecto o hacer rebuild e aparece este error y no termina el proceso.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\a_sua\OneDrive\Documentos\PROYECTOS\PubEat\app\src\main\java\pubeat\app\version1_0\MuroNegocio.java
Error:(15, 8) error: cannot access ActionBarActivity
class file for android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity not found
Error:(21, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(23, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(24, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
Error:(25, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setDragEdge(DragEdge)
Error:(28, 34) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
Error:(29, 53) error: cannot find symbol method getSupportFragmentManager()
Error:(31, 32) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
Error:(40, 50) error: cannot find symbol variable this
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
 Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED in 25s
Information:10 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: No se mucho de Android pero revisa que tengas tu Activity declarada en el manifiesto, por lo que no la pueda encontrar. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que añadir las librerías de Android Support Appcompat V7 a tu compilación.
Edita tu build.gradle y pon algo como esto en la sección de dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
```

El número 23.2.0 cambia regularmente. Android Studio te va a ofrecer la versión más nueva en el tooltip.

Comment: Si, de hecho en mi gradle tengo esta versión                                                     `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'` pero aun así me da el error.

Answer (score -1):

En tu proyecto usas la clase `ActionBarActivity`, la cual es **obsoleta**, solo puede ser usada si usas la dependencia de este última versión, pero lo cual **no es recomendable**:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```

Lo correcto es que debes cambiar a [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

La razón por la cual obtienes el mensaje:

> class file for android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity not found

es simplemente porque ya no existe en las últimas versiones de la support library.